# cpu_sup module snow leapord

Tags: erlang

When using cpu_sup module, it returns the following message. My os is mac snow leapord. Is it really true or just my installed erlang problem?

```
OS_MON (cpu_sup), util/1 unavailable for this OS
10> cpu_sup:util([per_cpu]).

=ERROR REPORT==== 12-Mar-2012::14:48:47 ===
OS_MON (cpu_sup), util/1 unavailable for this OS
{all,0,0,[]}
11> cpu_sup:util([cpus]).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  cpu_sup:util/1
13> cpu_sup:util([detailed]).
{all,0,0,[]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 12-Mar-2012::14:54:33 ===
```

OS_MON (cpu_sup), util/1 unavailable for this OS

Comment: Don't worry I just got burned in the same way. Stupid module. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the docs:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/cpu_sup.html

In the very first paragraph you find:

> Available for Unix, although CPU utilization values (util/0,1) are only available for Solaris and Linux.